# Record output voice from speaker . Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

how to record speaker output in blackberry is there any pai or hack to do so

for recording from mic i have used

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/1089414/How_To_-_Record_audio_on_a_BlackBerry_smartphone.html?nodeid=1311883&vernum=0

its doesnt specify how to recored speaker output

Comment: Not sure that you can, but wouldn't recording mic input while the device is outputting sound work just as well? (just realized you would also be capturing a lot of background noises etc. so i guess that's the downside)

Comment: i dont bother about noise i just want to record both mic and speaker sound simultaneously

Comment: so.. that's your answer then? just record the mic (which will pickup everything including sounds produced by the speakers at that time)

Comment: but speaker also have another sound for example voice od another caller and music player etc